# Ajax webmethod fails to fire a stored procedure on the first attempt only

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, azure, azure-sql-database

I have a webmethod that fails to fire a stored procedure during the first attempt only (I guess while establishing a new connection). I get `Internal error server` as an error Ajax message. However if I hit return from the URL address then the stored procedure is executed and pages work perfectly well, as they should. Then again if I keep the page inactive for a while and then try to establish a new connection the same problem occurs.

I spent the last 2 days trying to identify the problem by checking the parameters, removing most of the codes from the webmethod, and finally I was able to trace the problem to this stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spUnionServices]
@freetext NVARCHAR(50),
@offset int,
@fetch int

AS SET NOCOUNT ON;

BEGIN
SELECT IDphoto AS IDservice, photos.IDuser, photoCaption AS serviceTitle, photoDate as serviceDate, photoFileName AS servicePhoto, 'Photo' AS service,
    photoPublished as servicePublished, inap, hashtags, KEY_TBL.RANK, screenName AS IDname
    FROM photos INNER JOIN FREETEXTTABLE(photos, (photoCaption), @freetext) AS KEY_TBL ON photos.IDphoto = KEY_TBL.[KEY]
    INNER JOIN editorDetail ON editorDetail.IDuser = photos.IDuser
    ORDER BY RANK DESC OFFSET @offset ROWS FETCH NEXT @fetch ROWS ONLY  
END
```

And here is how I connect to the stored procedure from the webmethod

```
StringBuilder SBsmallSquares = new StringBuilder();
SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
           using (sqlConnection1)
           {
               SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
               SqlDataReader ReaderPopup;
               cmd.CommandText = "spUnionServices";
               cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
               cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@offset", offset);
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fetch", fetch);
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@freetext", fts);

               sqlConnection1.Open();
               ReaderPopup = cmd.ExecuteReader();
               if (ReaderPopup.HasRows)
               {
                   while (ReaderPopup.Read())
                   {
                   //creating the string to return. Here there is no problem.
                   }
                   return SBsmallSquares.ToString();
               }
            else return string.Empty;
```

I would appreciate it if someone could find out why I'm having this problem during the first attempt to run the stored procedure. Thanks!

Comment: when you debug your server-side webmethod code - what exception do you get there?

Comment: I don't get any error..... The only error I was able to catch is "Server Internal Error" from the Ajax webmethod

Comment: this cannot be. Something is failing on the server. Are you able to set a breakpoint inside webmethod and stop on it?

Comment: I managed to run the stored procedure outside the webmethod and here is the error: An error has occurred during the full-text query. Common causes include: word-breaking errors or timeout, FDHOST permissions/ACL issues, service account missing privileges, malfunctioning IFilters, communication channel issues with FDHost and sqlservr.exe, etc.

Comment: And again if I hit enter the stored procedure runs without error..... It's only the first attempt. Anyhelp???

Answer (score 0):

You should retry on this error. During availability events (upgrades for example) a DB can move to a different machine and fdhost needs to pair with the SQL instance again. Usually the pairing process happens on the first free text query or when needed. You may be seeing timeouts in that process for the first time. It should help you on retry. if this is very consistent there could be a bug in the service and let know. I will help you debug this further.

Comment: This error is happening with Azure Sql V12 which is the newset Azure database. In fact a similar behavior, caused by the SQL service failing to verify signature, started with SQL database 2005 and it was known to be a bug in the service, then Microsoft solved it with later versions.

I asked the same question on Azure support forum but no one bothered to answer yet.

Comment: And yes the error is very consistent.... I've tested the page on different machines and I got the same error result the first time.

Comment: Hi, I am the developer for this feature in SQL DB. Please retry the query in Asp.Net web page and we will investigate why the query is timing out and try to get a fix based on the priority. Thanks for letting us know.

Comment: I've been running a simple query that contains a full-text search on regular basis (every 15 minutes) for the last 4 days. The error is not consistent anymore which means that 90% of the FIRST requests (while establishing a new pool connection) run without eror. However it's very slow compared to other queries (without full-text search). A query that doesn't contain a fulltext search takes max 2 seconds from the the time you request the page until it has been loaded. Whereas the waiting time of a query that contains a fulltext search is 5 to 10 times more, during the first request only.

Answer (score 0):

I would put this in a comment but it's easier to write the code here in an answer.
I realize you said you are getting the error in ajax but it is occurring server side and being propagated back to your Ajax call. Because you do not have any exception handling in your code IIS is wrapping the exception for you using a generic exception with minimal detail.

You need to catch the exception server side and examine it, this should give you more detail and hopefully with that insight figuring out why it is occurring and then fixing it should be much easier.

```
StringBuilder SBsmallSquares = new StringBuilder();
SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = null;
try
{
    sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataReader ReaderPopup;
    cmd.CommandText = "spUnionServices";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@offset", offset);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fetch", fetch);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@freetext", fts);

    sqlConnection1.Open();
    ReaderPopup = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (ReaderPopup.HasRows)
    {
        while (ReaderPopup.Read())
        {
            //creating the string to return. Here there is no problem.
        }
        return SBsmallSquares.ToString();
    }
    else return string.Empty;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // write this out to a text file OR (if you can) examine the exception in the debugger
    // what you need are
    // 0. ex.StackTrace <- the full call stack that generated the exception, now you know what method call caused it
    // 1. ex.GetType().FullName <- the full type of the exception
    // 2. ex.Message <- the message in the exception
    // 3. ex.InnerException <- if this is not null then we need the type and message (1 and 2 above) again, this can recurse as many times as needed (the ex.InnerException can have an ex.InnerException.InnerException and that one can also have an InnerException, and so on)
    // 4. some exceptions have additional details in other properties depending on the type, if you see anything usefull get that too

    throw; // rethrow the exception because you do not want to ignore it and pretend everything succeeded (it didn't)
}
finally
{
    if(sqlConnection1 != null) sqlConnection1.Close();
}
```

**EDIT**

It is also possible to update the web site configuration in IIS (and the web.config I believe) to pass through the complete exception and the details. I am not sure if its just sql server that is hosted for you in Azure or also IIS. In the later case I am not familiar with how to configure it to allow this but it might be possible. You can sometimes also specify whether to only allow complete exception/error details when running on local host which is great when you are debugging as you want to see exception information when troubleshooting but you would prefer that the outside world (outside of your company) did not see any sensitive internal details.

You can google this for more information on how to enable it, if you are running IIS in Azure then add a keyword about Azure to the search. [Google: iis show exception](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=iis%20show%20exception)

Comment: Igor thanks for your answer. I think you've missed my comment above about the fact that I've already run the SQL query outside the webmethod and I got the following error from the server: An error has occurred during the full-text query. Common causes include: word-breaking errors or timeout, FDHOST permissions/ACL issues, service account missing privileges, malfunctioning IFilters, communication channel issues with FDHost and sqlservr.exe, etc....

It seems that it's an error caused by a bug in the system. I've already published my question on Azure support forum but never got an answer.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that there is a session authentication scheme that is not being initiated. You should try to perform a get first to allow cookies to be set in the browser. Alternatively have a closer examination of the cookies that are set on the successful attempt and work to align this if the information is available at the point of page generation.